# Fortran on Code Blocks_Linux Mint

Tags: gfortran

I start with using Code Blocks for programing in Fortan.
I created a console app, compiling with gnu fortran compiler and when i start with compiling i got this mesage:

> /media/aleksandar/HD_2/Programiranje/Code Blocks/Fortran/Aleksandar/main.f95|15|/media/aleksandar/HD_2/Programiranje/Code Blocks/Fortran/Aleksandar/main.f95 15 .1:|
>   ||Warning: Nonconforming tab character  |
>   /media/aleksandar/HD_2/Programiranje/Code Blocks/Fortran/Aleksandar/main.f95|15|/media/aleksandar/HD_2/Programiranje/Code Blocks/Fortran/Aleksandar/main.f95 15 .25:|
>   ||Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string  |
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 7 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

What is problem with my code?

This is my code:

```
Program KTO
!Program za sortiranje niza (rastuce i opadajuce vrijednosti)
Implicit none
Integer::i,n,Odabir
Real,dimension(24)::Ppot
Logical::Max
!Otvaranje datoteke sa podacima o potrosnji
!Kad se ucitava kolona na ovaj nacin uvijek ide n+1 broj ucitavanja
!Strogo paziti na ovo
Open(8,File='Ulaz',Status='OLD')   

    Read(8,'(i3,/,25(f5.1,/)')n,(Ppot(i),i=1,n) 

Close(8)
Write(*,'(2x,"Kakvo sortiranje zelite?",//,&
2x,"1 - Opadajuce vrijednosti?",/,&
2x,"2 - Rastuce vrijednost?")')
Read(*,'(i2)') Odabir
If (Odabir.eq.1) then
   Max=.true.
Else
   Max=.false.
End if
Call Sort(n,Ppot,Max)

! Ispis podataka u datoteku
Open(10,File='Izlaz',Status='Unknown')
    Write(10,'(1x,14hSortirani niz:,24(/,f5.1))') (Ppot(i),i=1,n)
Close(10)
Stop
End program KTO
!Potprogram za sortiranje
Subroutine Sort(n,Ppot,Max)
Implicit none
Integer::i,j
Integer,intent(in)::n
Real,dimension(n),intent(inout)::Ppot
Logical,intent(in)::Max
Real::Pom
If (Max.eqv..true.) then
   Do i=1,n-1
       Do j=i+1,n
          If (Ppot(i).lt.Ppot(j)) then
              Pom=Ppot(i)
              Ppot(i)=Ppot(j)
              Ppot(j)=Pom
          End if
       End do
   End do
Else
   Do i=1,n-1
      Do j=i+1,n
         If (Ppot(i).gt.Ppot(j)) then
              Pom=Ppot(i)
              Ppot(i)=Ppot(j)
              Ppot(j)=Pom
         End if
      End do
   End do

End if
Return
End subroutine Sort
```

Comment: Looks to me like a missing ) either after the 1 or after the ) after the 1.

Comment: Thanks Sami.
That is problem, exactly.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled the code with gfortran4.7.2. Then as @albert suggested, the following line turned out to be error:

```
Read(8,'(i3,/,25(f5.1,/)')n,(Ppot(i),i=1,n)
```

If this is fixed to

```
Read(8,'(i3,/,25(f5.1,/))')n,(Ppot(i),i=1,n)
                        ^--- added this
```

or

```
Read(8,'(i3,/,25(f5.1),/)')n,(Ppot(i),i=1,n)
                     ^--- added this
```

the code started to run, but it soon aborted because I have no file "Ulaz".

Comment: BTW, a Hollerith constant `14hSortirani niz:` is probably obsolete http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollerith_constant